# SoapClient: What's the difference between "Could not connect to host", "Network is unreachable" and "Connection timed out"

Tags: php, soap-client

I have some php exception logs where some say "Connection timed out", other logs say "Network is unreachable" and even other logs say "Could not connect to host"

What's the difference between the three messages + I'm wondering if SoapClient throws the default "Exception" or does it throw a "SoapFault"?

These are the exact error messages for both errors:

```
SoapClient::__doRequest(): connect() failed: Network is unreachable
SoapClient::__doRequest(): connect() failed: Connection timed out
Could not connect to host
```

Thanks.

Comment: Network is unreachable means there's no route to the network. Lets say you were trying to access 192.168.0.1, which is a private network address and your private network is something entirely different thus you can't reach it. Connection timed out on the other hand is something that you should be able to reach, but the server isn't responding.

Comment: @Augwa I'll just add the keyword "Firewall"

Comment: @Augwa Okay thanks. Do you know if these errors throw a SoapFault?